# implode() inside two foreach()

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
@foreach ($artists as $artist)
    <td>{{ $artist->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $artist->title }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach ($artist->tags as $tag)
            {{ $tag->id }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
@endforeach
```

How can i correctly output each `$tag->id` with comma's using `implode()`?

Tried to do this:

```
@foreach ($artist->tags as $tag)
    <?php $arr[] = $tag->id ?>
@endforeach
{{ implode(", ", $arr) }}
```

But because of 2 `foreach()` i am getting repeated tag's.

Comment: Do you want the tag id's of all artists as comma separated strings or one string per artist?

Comment: So you only want to filter out duplicates?

Comment: I guess you could do $arr[$tag->id] = $tag->id 

But I have to say that whatever is you're doing, it seems like you're taking the wrong approach. Doing this sort of thing in your template/html is probably not the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Laravels `lists()` function here. It will make an array of all tag id's:

```
{{ implode(', ', $artist->tags->lists('id')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is you doesn't clean your array before you add tags. Before you enter the second foreach create a new arr[].

Answer (score 1):

You can override the keys in `$arr`:

```
@foreach ($artist->tags as $tag)
    <?php $arr[$tag->id] = $tag->id; // <-- HERE ?>
@endforeach
{{ implode(", ", $arr) }}
```